# Implementing simple properties serializer

Tags: c#

I'm trying to parse several strings which represent objects. An object representation is the following:

`[property-name-1]:value1,[property-name-2]:value2,...[property-name-n]:value-n`

Object **Person** could be expressed like:

```
public class Person
{
  public enum Sex { DontKnow, Male, Female }

  private string _input;
  private string _name;
  private int _age;
  private Sex _sex;

  public Person(string str) { _input = str; ParseInput(); }

  protected readonly ReadOnlyCollection<string> _elems = Array.AsReadOnly(new string[] {"NAME", "AGE", "SEX"});

  //Input example
  //NAME:Jeff O'Connor,SEX:Male,AGE:18
  private void ParseInput()
  {
    var elements = _input.Split(',');
    List<int> ignore = new List<int>();

    foreach (string par in elements)
    {
      //All parameters got?
      if (ignore.Count == 3) break;
      for (int i = 0; i < _elems.Count; ++i)
      {
          string spar = _elems[i], dta;

          //Already got parameter or not actual parameter
          if (ignore.Contains(i) || !par.StartsWith(spar)) continue;
          dta = par.Remove(0, spar.Length + 1)
          ignore.Add(i);
          switch (i)
          {
              case 0: _name = dta; break;
              case 1: int.TryParse(dta, out _age); break;
              case 2: Sex.TryParse(dta, out _sex); break;
          }
          break;
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Object **Car** could be expressed like:

```
public class Car
{
  public enum Color { DontKnow, White, Back, Red, Blue, Gold, Silver, Bordeaux, Yellow, Green, Kaki, Orange }

  private string _input;
  private string _brand;
  private string _model;
  private Color _color;

  public Car(string str) { _input = str; ParseInput(); }

  protected readonly ReadOnlyCollection<string> _elems = Array.AsReadOnly(new string[] {"BRAND", "MODEL", "COLOR"});

  //Input example
  //BRAND:Porsche,MODEL:Panamera 4S,COLOR:Bordeaux
  private void ParseInput()
  {
    var elements = _input.Split(',');
    List<int> ignore = new List<int>();

    foreach (string par in elements)
    {
      //All parameters got?
      if (ignore.Count == 3) break;
      for (int i = 0; i < _elems.Count; ++i)
      {
          string spar = _elems[i], dta;

          //Already got parameter or not actual parameter
          if (ignore.Contains(i) || !par.StartsWith(spar)) continue;
          dta = par.Remove(0, spar.Length + 1)
          ignore.Add(i);
          switch (i)
          {
              case 0: _brand = dta; break;
              case 1: _model = dta; break;
              case 2: Color.TryParse(dta, out _color); break;
          }
          break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As anyone can see, both **Car** and **Person** classes use common properties and methods; so I can inherit a class containing them, in a proper way to fill all descendant properties. In fact, I could call a protected virtual method to reimplement in every descendant, according to the property index to process with this signature (instead of using a **switch**):

`protected virtual void ProcessToken(int propertyIndex, string propertyData);`

Nevertheless I would like to implement the top level class that instead of declaring `protected readonly ReadOnlyCollection<string> _elems`, I may use `protected readonly ReadOnlyCollection<PropertyDesc> _elems`, to be filled within descendants for their respective properties; having that `PropertyDesc` is, or may be:

```
public struct PropertyDesc
{
  public string PropertyName;
  public Type PropertyType;
  public object PropertyReference;
}
```

Is there any way I can do the former? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273) (don't just change your question to "How"). What is the actual question you have or what is the problem? Please [edit] your question to include the source code you currently have and the problem you have with them. Keep in mind that you might not need a base class for your parsing, it can be in a different class, maybe even with only static helper methods you simply call from the constructor.

Comment: It seems like there may be a large amount of non-relevant code, while the question itself is a little unclear. Yes, you can inherit from a base class or implement an interface that defines the common properties and methods. And you can have a custom type as a property as well. When you try this, what errors do you get? What exactly is the problem or question here?

Comment: Sorry for poorly asking the question. The real thing that I wanted to set object's properties from an input string describing it, without repeating the implementation of `ParseInput` in every object. Like @Progman said, I could make a different class with such a method, but instead I found a solution, using a delegate to get descendant's properties. This is my new working code:  [link](https://pastebin.com/3zyUcMbc). For this problem I've tried to implement class member references like in C++ std::bind ([link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind)), but no success on it.